# c# synchronous operations strange order

Tags: c#, textbox, synchronization, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a small application with only a `Button` and a `TextBox`. So, when I click button I have to modify text and send some HTTP requests, nothing more. But the text must be modified before any requests are made. I'm doing both operations (text setting and requests) in one thread and all the requests are synchronous `HttpWebRequest` (because nothing can be done until all requests are finished). This is my click handler code:

```
messageTb.Text = "Connecting...";
doRequests();
```

But it works a little bit strange: first, I get all my requests done and only after this the text gets modified.

Comment: That is because you're doing it in the GUI thread. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128670/force-redraw-before-long-running-operations

Comment: Try writing `this.Refresh()` after the `messageTb.Text` line. I think that the GUI is not updated before the web request starts, and then because the web request is blocking the UI cannot be updated. You can either force the UI to redraw, or (better) do the request on a background thread

Comment: @smoksnes Yes, but text changing is a synchronous operation, so the text must be changed regardless of what's done after.

Comment: @JustLogin the UI is not required to update immediately when you change the text of one of its controls.

Comment: @Oliver I haven't got `Refresh` method in my class (it extends `Window`).

Comment: If your application is WPF - then this may be a useful link : http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx - it shows how to write a Refresh extension method. (Take note of the 9th comment about WIndows 7).